# Antecedent of pronoun

Tags: pronouns

How to place pronoun in sentence  as antecedent  and what is the rules.

> Sahani send a book to Reemi to read and she will give to her friend after that.

My point is the "she" refer to who? Sahani or Reemi?  I want someone ti explain me the real ruls that can clear my confusion when I speak such sentence without any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could give you a simple rule to follow that would help in this situation, but unfortunately, even native speakers often use *ambiguous* pronouns.  For example, my wife likes to ask me:

> Could you get that thing out of there and give it to her?  Thanks!

Which thing?  From where?  Give it to who?  What?  I have no idea what she wants me to do.

Ok, so I exaggerate.  But the point is that, sometimes you can understand from context what each pronoun refers to.  Sometimes you have to ask for additional information.

In your example sentence we can make a guess that both "she" and "her" refer to Reemi not Sahani, because Reemi is the one who will have the book -- but we don't know for sure.  If it's important, we have to ask for more information.  When constructing these kind of sentences, if you think there will be any confusion, it's fine to repeat the noun.

> Sahani will give the book to Reemi, and then **Reemi** will give it to her friend.
>
> Can you get the book from under that magazine, and then put **the book** back on the shelf?  Thanks.